# When adding an activity, a new contact can be created, but it only asks for name and email. How to configure (add fields)?

Tags: activities, configuration, documentation

When a CiviCRM user adds an activity, there is an option of adding a new contact through a pop-up (instead of selecting a contact). I can't find any documentation on whether/how this form can be customized. I'm also not a programmer.

For the organization I work for, it would be extremely helpful to be able to add a bit more info at this stage (at least the phone number, ideally a few other fields). To do so, do we need to modify code (and if so, where) or is there an easier way to configure which fields appear here (ideally through profile, I suppose)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steve welcome to CiviCRM stack exchange. Yes you can add more fields to the form. They are rendered from profile.

1. Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Profiles
2. Click on Reserved profiles tab
3. Find for 'New Organization', click on 'Fields' link
4. Add more fields you would like to have. You can only add contact and organization field else the form won't be rendered and through error.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you very much Pradeep. Somehow I looked at Profiles at least three times without noticing that there was a tab with Reserved Profiles.